# SQL script cshell

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, spool

I am doing this in my cshell script `sqlplus $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD @${SQL}test.sql ${DATA}${ext1}`thats trying to get output from test.sql script.. in my sql script i am dumping output to `spool &1` .. but when i run my script my files are blank i am not getting anything from database.. can someone tell what wrong with this

Comment: That looks OK; does the SQL produce any output to screen or when run manually, and what (if any) `SET` calls do you have in the `.sql` file? Showing the whole SQL might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, sql is producing output when i am running it manually.. here is sql script: SET LINESIZE 1000
SET LONG 100000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET SPACE 1
SET FLUSH OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET NUMFORMAT 9999999999.90

SPOOL &1

Select
..............
From
..............
where
.............

SPOOL OFF
Exit;

Comment: You should see the results on screen as well as in the file (`SET termout off` to avoid that later). Do you have a terminating `;` or `/` to actually execute the query, or just a blank line between the end of the `where` clause and the `spool off`? Hard to tell without formatting - perhaps it could go in the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

normally it is not a good idea to have your userid and password displayed in the processlist, as is happening now. Most of the times when sql scripts don't produce the expected output it is because the end of SQL marker is missing. Default the end of SQL is the ';' Reading the end of SQL marker actually starts the SQL statement.
First try the script with feedback on and check the error message in the spoolfile.
Is the spoolfile location OK ?

```
sqlplus /nolog <<eof
connect $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD
@${SQL}test.sql ${DATA}${ext1}
eof
```

This construction prevents the display of the credentials on the processlist.

In the sqlscript could be

```
select * from dual;
```

or

```
select * from dual
/
```

but each and every SQL statement has to have an end of SQL marker.